# [unixODBC][Devart][ODBC][MongoDB]Cannot load client library: libmongoc-1.0.so.0 (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)') Error

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos, odbc

I have installed ODBC Driver for MongoDB on EC2 instance(Linux/Unix) on AWS(RPM package) using

```
sudo yum localinstall devart-odbc-mongo.x86_64.rpm
```

Driver downloaded from : https://www.devart.com/odbc/mongodb/download.html (ODBC Driver for MongoDB 2.0 RPM x64) version

Installation notes:
**DRIVER MONGODB**
[root@ip-172-31-15-248 /]# `rpm -qi devart-odbc-mongo.x86_64`

> Name        : devart-odbc-mongo Version     : 2.0.5 Release     : 1
> Architecture: x86_64 Install Date: Tue 27 Apr 2021 01:25:50 AM UTC
> Group       : Development/Libraries Size        : 10407189 License
> : GPL Signature   : (none) Source RPM  :
> devart-odbc-mongo-2.0.5-1.src.rpm Build Date  : Tue 15 Dec 2020
> 10:54:47 AM UTC Build Host  : dac-centos7x64 Relocations : (not
> relocatable) URL         : https://devart.com/odbc/mongodb Summary
> : New level of functionality and performance in data access via ODBC
> Description : Devart ODBC Driver for MongoDB provides a
> high-performance and feature-rich connectivity solution for ODBC-based
> applications to access MongoDB databases from Windows, macOS, Linux.
> Full support for standard ODBC API functions, MongoDB data types and
> SQL queries implemented in our driver makes interaction of your
> database applications with MongoDB fast, easy and extremely handy.

**UNIXODBC:**
[root@ip-172-31-15-248 /]# `rpm -qi unixODBC`

> Name        : unixODBC Version     : 2.3.1 Release     : 14.amzn2
> Architecture: x86_64 Install Date: Sun 25 Apr 2021 01:07:41 AM UTC
> Group       : System Environment/Libraries Size        : 1263147
> License     : GPLv2+ and LGPLv2+ Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Tue 05 Nov
> 2019 10:11:35 PM UTC, Key ID 11cf1f95c87f5b1a Source RPM  :
> unixODBC-2.3.1-14.amzn2.src Build Date  : Wed 14 Aug 2019 12:36:47 AM
> UTC Build Host  : build.amazon.com Relocations : (not relocatable)
> Packager    : Amazon Linux Vendor      : Amazon Linux URL         :
> http://www.unixODBC.org/ Summary     : A complete ODBC driver manager
> for Linux Description : Install unixODBC if you want to access
> databases through ODBC. You will also need the mysql-connector-odbc
> package if you want to access a MySQL database, and/or the
> postgresql-odbc package for PostgreSQL.

Updated the odbc ini file as below:

> [DEVART_MONGODB]    Driver=Devart ODBC Driver for MongoDB    Data
> Source=IP address    Port=27017    Database=instacart    Client
> Library=libmongoc-1.0.so.0    BSON Library=libbson-1.0.so.0

odbcinst ini content are below:

> [ODBC Drivers]
> Devart ODBC Driver for MongoDB=installed
>
> [Devart ODBC Driver for MongoDB]
> Driver=/lib/libdevatodbcmongo.so
>
> [ODBC Data Sources]
> DEVART_MONGODB=Devart ODBC Driver for MongoDB

ENVIRONMENT IS ALSO SET:

> [root@ip-172-31-15-248 /]# `env |grep 'ODBC'` ODBCSYSINI=/etc
> ODBCINI=/etc/odbc ini

when I try to test the connection with the below command:

```
isql -v DEVART_MONGODB
```

the error show is:
[root@ip-172-31-15-248 /]# `isql -v DEVART_MONGODB`
[S1000][unixODBC][Devart][ODBC][MongoDB]Cannot load client library: `libmongoc-1.0.so.0`
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Can anyone help me to resolve this error??

Comment: were you able to resolve it?